# Eclipse - how can I handle EL 2.2 concat in xhtml?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I'm using EL 2.2 with Eclipse in xhtml pages.
How can I tell Eclipse to resolve keys with .concat(), like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{'message.xx.'.concat(cc.attrs.type)]}" />
```

Obvious the key does not exist in resrouce bundle in that way, bc it is dynamically build by the concat.
So Eclipse constantly claims of an invalid expression, further the xhtml pages are marked that they contain an error. Although it works in the webapp without a problem!

This is really annoying, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite sure how you defined your bundle name , but lets call it `bundleName`

so use `<ui:param` to build your desired key , no `.concat` usage needed

incase you can access the `cc.attrs.type` by `#{cc.attrs.type}`

```
<ui:param name="messageSuffix" value="message.xx.#{cc.attrs.type}"></ui:param>
<h:outputText value="#{bundleName[messageSuffix]}" />
```

Comment: Did you test this in eclipse? It works in webapp. BUT eclipse complains: "messageSuffix cannot be resolved". So the problem just gets shifted :/

Comment: My eclipse does not complain about this... but i guess it depends on your local eclipse settings...

Comment: hm that's really strange as I use latest indigo. do you know where to find settings converning this??

Comment: try window->preferences and type validation in the upper input text filter.. ans start looking maybe html or jsf or xml validation might help...